# Sentence formation in short

Tags: sentence-construction

I brought a gift from Mumbai and i brought it for you.
Can I write the above sentence in short  like. I brought a gift from Mumbai for you.

Comment: Yes, you can. But you'd need to make significant changes if you wanted to remove the potential ambiguity (was I ***in Mumbai*** when I bought it from a seller there ***in person***, or did I simply order it on eBay while sitting at home in the UK (buying from a trader based in Mumbai)?

Comment: @FumbleFingers There don't need to be any significant changes at all—just the addition of a single word: *I brought a gift **back** from Mumbai for you.*

Comment: @JasonBassford: I stand corrected! But at least maybe my comment may give heart to learners daunted by the scale of preposition use in English, when they realise that even competent native speakers can't necessarily call to mind the most efficient way to convey potentially significant disambiguation.